# migration wordpress website to another host problem

Tags: wordpress, migration, new-operator, host

i want to transfer my wordpress(woocommerce) website to another host, ihave jst do that :
1- download all my files (wp-content, wd-admin, ....etc) from my old host.
2- export my database
3- create new database on the new host
4- import my old database
5- update the wp-config file with new connection to my new database.
6- upload all my files to the new host
all is right , the problem is that when i update the name server of my domain 
when i try to get my website? IT REDIRECT ME THE INSTALL WORDPRESS PAGE 
i don't understand where is the problem

Comment: So the domain / hostname hasn't changed, just the server?

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: the domain still the same, ihave just change the host

Answer (score 0):

So transferring a wordpress site should be very easy. Just quoting your steps out:

> 1- download all my files (wp-content, wd-admin, ....etc) from my old host. 2- export my database 3- create new database on the new host 4- import my old database 5- update the wp-config file with new connection to my new database. 6- upload all my files to the new host all is right

Have you changed the new site url in the wp_options table in the wordpress database using phpmyadmin?

These are the actual steps you need to follow:

1) Zip the full current files you have on your old wordpress site's file directory. And I mean everything. If you want to use FTP to download the files, that's an option as well instead of zipping it and downloading via a file manager if your host has cPanel or anything equivalent to it.

2) Go to phpmyadmmin on your old server and export the database of the old site. Pretty easy to do this.

3) Upload the zipped files to your new server's domain root and unzip them.

4) Import the old database into the new database you created on the new host.

5) Change the Site urls in the wp_options table to the new URL.

Then you can load the backend and do a search replace of all old URLs with the new URLs using a search and replace plugin for wordpress.

Comment: the site url still the same i haven't change it , the domaine still the same, should i change it ?

Comment: i know that is very easy i have transfert another website last days , but i don't understand why i have the install wordpress page have you any idea ?

Comment: Okay so I read above that the domain is the same and you just switched hosts. In the Wp-config file did you enter the right database credentials? Check the database host also. Not all hosts run on 'localhost'

Comment: i think it's just little different between domains : the old is https:// and the new one http:// i must install the certificate , can that cause the problem ?? call the WP install page ??

Comment: Nope that won't be the problem. But if you don't have a SSL certificate installed yet, please change the URL to http:// for now. I think its a very simple fix, I can help you solve it for sure.

Comment: As i said in my previous comment, I think you need to check the DB host field and see if you entered the right database host

Comment: i zip the files on the old host - i download thems , and upload thems to new host , i export the database, i create new database on the new host , i import my database, on the new server, i update wp-config.php with new informations, when i enter to my website on the new host : i have page to install new WP.

Comment: strange  problem, i have install the same site with another domain, i update on the database with the url of the new domain, all work .....ok

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved, as that :
the url was : https:// but in the new server the ssl certificate is generated automatic , so it dosen't word but when i change the url to http all is work, thanks for all , and i hope it help new people who have the same problem ,